# Could not load file or assembly System.Data.SQLite - Web App deployed

Tags: asp.net, .net, sqlite, iis, iis-7.5

i know this is a duplicate question but i can't figure it out.

**The Error Message:**

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite' or one of it's
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

**The Context:**
I am using VS2012, MVC4, .Net 4.5 to build a web application.
The application uses an other solution which contains the SQLite.dll with copy local.
I tried to deploy my web application on a Win2008 R2 server but i get the above error message.
I compile for Any CPU my dev. enviroment is Win7 x64 and my server also x64

**What i tried:**
**1.** Tried copying the msvcr100.dll to the deployed bin folder because it it a dependency of the SQLite

**2.** Tried to copy to the bin folder the SQLite.dll and the SQLite.Linq.dll from my dev. enviroment

**3.** Tried setting Enable 32 - Bit Applications" to false and also true for the app pool that i am using in IIS 7.5

**4.** Tried to restart IIS, added the Network Service and IIS user to have access to my folder.

**5.** Followed this post [System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181018/system-io-fileloadexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite), I use the version V1.0.88 which is now a pretty old version which i guess was cleaned, maybee i should try and  even older version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running SQLite in 64 bit OS, try use x64 version of System.Data.SQLite.DLL

Download: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki